# Retain original suffix in piped command chain

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that searches for files that have duplicate main part of filename:

E.g. "IMAGE123.MOV" and "IMAGE123.JPG".

The script looks like this:

```
find . -iname "*.mov" -o -iname "*.jpg" | cut -d'.' -f2 | uniq -d |uniq | awk '{print "."$1".mov"}'
```

I could pipe this to "rm" with xargs to delete the files. But the issue is that I do not know if the file had ".MOV" or ".mov" suffix. I use awk to concatenate lowercase - but I am not sure if that was correct. This information gets lost during the command chain here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easier to find ***.mov** and test if there is a corresponding ***.jpg**. Here is how I'd do it:

```
find . -name '*.[Mm][Oo][Vv]' -exec sh -c '
for mov; do
  for jpg in "${mov%.*}".[Jj][Pp][Gg]; do
    if test -f "$jpg"; then
      echo rm "$mov"
    fi
    break
  done
done' sh {} +
```

Remove `echo` if the output looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, `sort -u` is more powerful than `uniq`.
You can use it without `cut`.

```
find . -iname "*.mov" -o -iname "*.jpg" |
sort -f -u -k1,1 -t. -r
```

The parameters of sort mean the following:

- `-f` Ignore case
- `-u` Unique
- `-k1,1` Consider only the first field for uniqueness/sorting
- `-t.` Consider the dot as the field separator
- `-r` Reverse sort (so .mov files appear first)

This will return the first ocurrence of each filename, no matter the case or the file extension.

Comment: I tried this - but unfortunately it returned the files that was not going to be deleted (the JPG).